# Different objects to the same webgrid control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I have a list of csv files to choose from a dropdown list. The data for each csv is different.  I'm pulling in csv files and want to display the data using the same webgrid.  Would I pass dynamic object to the webgrid, so the webgrid can display the columns and values for all the csv data?  If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could use a dynamic view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedCsv { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableCsv {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "foo.csv", Text = "foo.csv" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "bar.csv", Text = "bar.csv" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "baz.csv", Text = "baz.csv" },
            };
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> Data { get; set; }
}
```

and then have a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Data = GetData("foo.csv"),
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        model.Data = GetData(model.SelectedCsv);
        return View(model);
    }

    // TODO: move this method away in a repository and
    // do the actual parsing of the CSV file
    private IEnumerable<object> GetData(string csv)
    {
        if (csv == "foo.csv")
        {
            return new[] 
            { 
                new { col1 = "value1", col2 = "value2" },
                new { col1 = "value1", col2 = "value2" },
            };
        }
        else if (csv == "bar.csv")
        {
            return new[] 
            { 
                new { col1 = "bar value1", col2 = "bar value2", col3 = "bar value3" },
            };
        }
        else if (csv == "baz.csv")
        {
            return new[] 
            { 
                new { col1 = "baz value1" },
                new { col1 = "baz value2" },
                new { col1 = "baz value3" },
            };
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and in the view:

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCsv, Model.AvailableCsv)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}

@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model.Data);
}

@grid.GetHtml()
```

As far as the parsing of the CSV file is concerned, if there's was a single thing you should **never** do, that would be to [roll your own CSV parser](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp).